# Fetching audio from API - creating play next sound button

Tags: api, button, audio

I'm fetching the audio from an API, playing it til end, then fetching new file. Then I've added a button that is supposed to fetch a new audiofile from the API and play it - but I can not make the currently playing file stop. It just starts playing another file, loops my fetch function, and all of a sudden I have 2 loops playing and fetching files. This is my button code:

```
  $("#newbird").click(function() {
    // Fetch all audio that is playing and pause it
    activeAudio.pause();
    birdFunction();
  })
```

I store the current audio file in a global variable (activeAudio) and then try to pause it through the on-click function, but it does not pause the audio.

```
var birdFile = (response.recordings[0].file);
var audio = new Audio(birdFile);
audio.play(audio);
audio.loop = true;
activeAudio = audio;
```

The activeAudio.pause(); obviously isn't working - what should I do here?

Comment: You need to maintain references to audio that's playing. There's no built-in I'm aware of that "automagically" references active audio.

Comment: I store the current audio file in a global variable (activeAudio) and then try to pause it through the on-click function, but it does not pause the audio.

`var birdFile = (response.recordings[0].file);
var audio = new Audio(birdFile);
audio.play(audio);
audio.loop = true;
activeAudio = audio; `

Comment: And you're sure that value `activeAudio` doesn't get overwritten between then and `activeAudio.pause()`? Use a debugger and set a breakpoint at `activeAudio.pause()`, then look at the value of `activeAudio` to make sure it's what you expected it to be.

Comment: The other problem is you're invoking `audio.play()` before the `src` has had a chance to buffer, so it's not really clear when or if playing will actually commence. You should probably call `audio.play()` inside of `audio.oncanplaythrough = function () { ... }` so that it's guaranteed to work as expected.